# How to refactor this function to solve cyclomatic issue?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to fix this error on codeclimate

> Cyclomatic complexity for resource_icon is too high. [7/6]

What is the best way to refactor this function?

```
def resource_icon(resource)
    case resource.to_sym
    when :locations
      'fa-building'
    when :monitored_places
      'fa-globe'
    when :attendances
      'fa fa-bicycle'
    when :gym_distribuitions
      'fa fa-users'
    when :ranking_activities
      'fa fa-list-ol'
    when :attendance_by_group_class_trainers
      'fa fa-graduation-cap'
    else
      'fa-diamond'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please explain how this code is to be used, in context.  See [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a hash that maps "locations" to "fa-building", "monitored_places" to "fa-globe", and so on, with a default value of "fa-diamond".

Comment: Indeed : `h = {locations: 'fa-building', monitored_places: 'fa-globe', attendances: 'fa fa-bicycle', gym_distribuitions: 'fa fa-users', ranking_activities: 'fa fa-list-ol', attendance_by_group_class_trainers: 'fa fa-graduation-cap'}; h.default = 'fa-diamond'; h`